# codeblocks compilation error no match for operator <<

Tags: c++, codeblocks, operator-keyword, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n; 
cin<<n<<endl;
string Eqs[100];
for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
    getline(cin,Eqs[i]);
}
```

i keep getting this error: no match for operator <<' (operator types are'std::istream {aka std:: basic_istream }' and int' )

I am just a beginner so please help.

Comment: `cout<<` or `cin>>`. Please explain what your `cin<<` is supposed to achieve.

Comment: `std::cin` has the contents of standard input, which it then 'pipes' (`>>`) to variables. `std::cout` gets contents and sends them to standard output, being 'piped to' (`<<`) by variables.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin), which is a [`std::istream`, a.k.a. `std::basic_istream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) (as mentioned by the error message). Look through the documentation for `std::istream`; there is no `operator<<` defined, but there is an `operator>>`.

The streaming operators were chosen to indicate the flow of data. When you write "`cin<<n`", the arrows are pointing towards `cin`, so the suggested meaning is that you want the value that is in `n` to be sent to the keyboard (which makes no sense). If you want data to flow from the keyboard to your variable, you need to reverse the arrows: `cin>>n`.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is the  <<endl after the n.

It has to be: cin<<n; that's all.

Comment: That is incorrect. The other answer already explains correctly what the issue is, namely that it should be `>>`, not `<<`. (The wrong use of `endl` is only a secondary issue.)